# Proving closure of a set

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Here's my question: I think I understand it but just don't really know how to put it into formal mathematical proof language.

Let $S_n$ be the set of all reals that can be constructed as a sum of n inverses of positive integers. Show that $\bar{S}_2 = S_2 \cup{0}$.

So this set is all numbers in the reals that can be written as the sum of two whole number fractions (like 1/3+1/5, 1/2+1/2, etc.). Since the closure includes the limit point, I understand zero just needs to be added to the set; obviously since it's positive integers zero isn't already in the set and the set includes reals arbitrarily close to zero (like 1/1,000,000 + 1/8,000,000) it makes sense that zero is the limit point.

To write this proof would it be enough just to state that zero is not in $S_2$ and show that any ball around zero contains some arbitrarily chosen point?

Comment: I think you meant *closure* in the title, and I don't think $1/1,000,000+3/8,000,000$ is in $S_2$ (because of the $3$)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes sorry typo and then hastily and poorly chosen example

Comment: Given any $\epsilon>0$, could you find an element of $S_2$ less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: definitely! does it suffice to say that there always exists an element of $S_2$ less than $\epsilon$ away from zero then?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct to show $S_2\cup \{0\}\subseteq \bar{S}_2$. The other direction is the difficulty: Are all non-zero limit points of the form $\dfrac{a+b}{ab}$? Why can't we e.g.  approximate $\sqrt{2}$ by numbers from $S_2$?

Comment: @MariusS.L. $S_2$ can't contain irrationals since we can't take an infinite sum. Since with only two numbers we can't get arbitrarily close to numbers that aren't in $S_2$ yes to the first part.

Comment: @boudreaux: "Since with only two numbers we can't get arbitrarily close to numbers that aren't in $S_2$." - This has to be proven. It is the interesting part. I don't see that this is true without a proof. You get arbitrarily close to $0$, so why not to $1/\pi$?

Comment: @boudreaux: "$S_2$ can't contain irrationals since we can't take an infinite sum." is not a valid argument. It is as if you said: I can't compute $\pi$ up to 4 digits because I have no computer. You must show that the method you have does not work.

Comment: @MariusS.L. I think you misinterpreted that a little or I put it poorly - since no irrational can be expressed as a sum of a finite number of integer fractions they aren't in $S_2$ and aren't limit points since (not sure how to put this in more formal language) we only can work with two fractions so to be able to get arbitrarily close to them one of your two fractions would have to equal the irrational number you're approaching so you could let the other get arbitrarily small. If we were working in $S_infty$ irrationals would still not be included but all be limit points.

Comment: @boudreaux " ... so to be able to get arbitrarily close to them one of your two fractions would have to equal the irrational number you're approaching..." - Why that? Why can't we have a sequence of numbers $\dfrac{a_n+b_n}{a_nb_n}$ such that the limit of such a sequence is irrational? $\pi $ can be approached by chain fractions, so maybe we can approach $1/\pi$ by numbers of that type. How can you be sure, that this is impossible? Think of Fibonacci numbers approaching $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ for instance.

Comment: @MariusS.L. Any example I feel it's easy to see - for $1/\pi$ for instance in $S_2$ you could choose 1/4 + 1/15 but how do you get closer than that? you could try to do some sum involving 1/5 or 1/6 but in practice it will be easy to find the closest value you could get to it, which means you can't get arbitrarily close so it isn't a limit point. I don't know how to translate this into a general proof though.

Comment: This is why it is difficult and not obvious. You gave an intuition, but that is no proof. Your example works for $1/\pi$, but what about other numbers? And there are really many irrational numbers close to zero. You have to prove, that for any number between 0 and 1, there is a limit you cannot go below, i.e. show that any algorithm that comes to an end in finitely many steps.